# Update fragment with viewpager in order to play videos

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have an RSS app and i'm using a viewpager to get from one article to another.
my problem is that , if i open an article from the list, i can always play the videos in it. If i move between the articles (with swipe),i can't play the videos.

So, i guess i have to refresh the fragment when i swipe?Is that the solution?

this is my fragment adapter:

```
public class DescAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public DescAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        entry = new HotOrNot_all(DetailActivity.this);
        entry.open();
        long count = entry.fetchPlacesCount();
        entry.close();
        return (int) count;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        DetailFragment frag = new DetailFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putInt("pos", position);

        frag.setArguments(bundle);


        return frag;

    }

}
```

DetailActivity.java

```
public class DetailActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    int pos;
    private DescAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    private HotOrNot_all entry;
    String TITLE;
    String CAT;
    String DESC;
    String ROWID;
    String IMAGE;
    String DATE;
    String LINK;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail);

        Log.i(this.getComponentName().toString(), "Started");
        pos = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 


        // Initialize the views
        adapter = new DescAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Set Adapter to pager:
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            this.
            finish();

            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.animation_slide_out_right);

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_slide_in_left,
                R.anim.animation_slide_out_right);

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public class DescAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public DescAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            entry = new HotOrNot_all(DetailActivity.this);
            entry.open();
            long count = entry.fetchPlacesCount();
            entry.close();
            return (int) count;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            DetailFragment frag = new DetailFragment();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            // bundle.putSerializable("list",TITLE_LIST);

            bundle.putInt("pos", position);

            frag.setArguments(bundle);


            return frag;

        }

    }

}
```

DetailFragment.java

```
public class DetailFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    private int fPos;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    String TITLE;
    String CAT;
    String DESC;
    String ROWID;
    String IMAGE;
    String DATE;
    String LINK;
    private HotOrNot_all entry;
    static Typeface roboto_bold;
    static Typeface roboto_regular;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

        roboto_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");

        roboto_regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        Log.i(this.getActivity().toString(), "Started");
        fPos = getArguments().getInt("pos");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, container,
                false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        entry = new HotOrNot_all(getActivity());
        entry.open();
        Cursor c = entry.getAllData();

        if (c.moveToPosition(fPos)) {

            TITLE = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.TITLE));
            CAT = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.CATEGORY));
            DESC = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.DESCRIPTION));
            ROWID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.ROWID));
            IMAGE = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.IMAGE));
            DATE = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.DATE));
            LINK = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.LINK));

        }

        c.close();
        entry.close();
        // Initializr views
        final TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setTypeface(roboto_bold);
        final TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setTypeface(roboto_regular);

        final TextView categg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.categg);
        categg.setTypeface(roboto_regular);

        final WebView desc = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

        desc.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                desc.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                        + "document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.display = 'none'; "
                        + "})()");
            }
        });


        // Enable the vertical fading edge (by default it is disabled)
        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.sv);
        sv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);

        // Set webview properties
        WebSettings ws = desc.getSettings();

        ws.setSupportZoom(true);
        // ws.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        ws.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        ws.setLightTouchEnabled(false);
        ws.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.766.0 Safari/534.36");

        // ws.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
        // desc.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

        desc.loadDataWithBaseURL("", DESC,
                "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        final WebView web = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        web.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        // read string from reader
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        web.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(false);
        web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

        web.getSettings()
                .setUserAgentString(
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");

        web.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
        web.loadDataWithBaseURL(IMAGE,
                "<img src=\" \" width=\"100%\" border=\"2\"/>", "text/html",
                "utf-8", null);

        // ----------------------------------------------------###############################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

        // Set the views
        title.setText(TITLE);


        final Button linkBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.linkBtn);
        linkBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        linkBtn.setTypeface(roboto_regular);
        linkBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                web.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                categg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                linkBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                desc.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(view
                        .getContext());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading  website ...");

                progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                progressDialog.show();
                desc.loadUrl(LINK);

                desc.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,
                            String url) {
                        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        view.scrollTo(0, 0);

                        return true;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                // linkBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.favorite_option2:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; finish activity to go home
            // grafei stin vasi dedomenwn
            // ------------------------

            HotOrNot_favorite entry = new HotOrNot_favorite(this.getActivity());
            entry.open();

            if (entry.Exists(LINK) == true) {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.favorite_empty_gr);

                entry.deleteItemByLink(LINK);

            } else {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.favorite_full_gr);

                entry.createEntryNea(TITLE, DESC, LINK, DATE, IMAGE, CAT);

                // entry.update(msg.getTitle(),msg.getagonistiki(),msg.getskor(),msg.getgipedo(),msg.getDate());


                // ----------------------------------------
            }

            entry.close();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_desc, menu);
        MenuItem switchButton = menu.findItem(R.id.favorite_option2);
        HotOrNot_favorite entry = new HotOrNot_favorite(this.getActivity());
        entry.open();

        if (entry.Exists(LINK) == true) {

            switchButton.setIcon(R.drawable.favorite_full_gr);

        }

        entry.close();

        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.share_option);

        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) shareItem
                .getActionProvider();

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain"); // eixe text/plan
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getText(R.string.app_name)
                + " Android App");

        if ((LINK != null) && (TITLE != null)) {

            String shareBody = Html.fromHtml(TITLE + "<br><br>")
                    + LINK
                    + Html.fromHtml("<br><br>Send from "
                            + getText(R.string.app_name) + " Android App");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);

            // Set the share intent
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        }

        else {

            String shareBody = LINK;
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);

            // Set the share intent
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

        }

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }


}
```

Comment: Could we see the code for DetailFragment. I know it might be large, but we do need all of it since it's likely a life cycle problem.

Comment: @Pork i have added the hole class

Comment: Could I see DetailFragment.java please?

Comment: @Pork added this too!

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but could you put in the default empty constructor for DetailFragment, public DetailFragment().

ViewPager can sometimes complain about it being missing, but it might not be the only problem.

Comment: public DetailFragment(){} ?? i have tried it but nothing changes

Comment: You need to call super(); in a default constructor.